# Print integer in 4 rows and 4 column Java without Array

Tags: java

I am supposed to create a program that prints out the following:

```
1 5 9  13
2 6 10 14
3 7 11 15
4 8 12 16
```

Here's my current code:

```
int n = 1,
    cols = 4,
    rows = 4;

for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= cols; j++) {
        System.out.print(n+" ");
        n++;
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

But the output is as below:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16
```

Can someone please help to figure out the solution for this one? I've tried many ways but just can't get the output right. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java can only print in lines and not in columns. So the first line you need to print is:

```
1   5   9   13
```

In other words, every successive number is 4 greater than the number preceding it. So start your outer loop with the first number of the first row, i.e. 1 (one). Now each row contains 4 numbers, so your inner loop needs to iterate four times. See the below code:

```java
int rows = 4;
int cols = 4;
for (int row = 1; row <= rows; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
        int number = row + (col * cols);
        System.out.print(number + "\t");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Running the above code produces the following:

```
1   5   9   13  
2   6   10  14  
3   7   11  15  
4   8   12  16
```

Answer (score 2):

Change inner loop to go from 0 to cols-1 rather than 1 to cols, and make it print outer loop variable + (inner loop variable * 4).

Answer (score 1):

This will surely work:

```
for(int row=1, num; row<=4; row++)
{
    num = row;
    for(int col=1; col<=4; col++, num+=4)
    {
        System.out.print(num + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```